# 230VAC to 230VDC converter for flicker free LED construction lights for use in videography/photography

Tags: voltage-regulator, bridge-rectifier, smoothing-capacitor

We use LED construction lights for illuminating a photo or video set. As espected the lights flicker with the mains frequency. While in some cases this can be compensated with the right camerasettings it would be a lot easier if the flickering could be removed.
The lights have total of 100W at 230V/50Hz.
[Osram LED worklight 2x50W](https://www.ledvance.com/professional/products/luminaires/professional-luminaires/worklights/versatile-led-worklights/versatile-led-worklight-with-tripod-stand-c8995)

So I started out with a simple idea. A full-wave bridge rectifier with a smoothing capacitor. I had 22μF/400V capacitor and a 2W08G rectifier. The lights already flicker a lot less but the capacitor would need to be bigger of course.

A larger capacitor will result in a smoother DC, hoever that DC is still close to 325VDC which means way more power for the LEDs. Since I have no idea what, if any, electronics the lights have inside (I can not open them without likely breaking them), I do not know if thats an issue. I mean the lights have to deal with that voltage and current at the top of the sine curve, but only for a brief moment. With 325VDC I would expect the lights to get way hotter than allowed and eventually fail.

---

**Questions:**

1. Are my assumptions correct so far, or can I go with this simple solution for this application?
2. If I can go with 1., do I need any extra restiors to protect the rectifier and/or capacitor?
3. Is there a cheap (no more than 30€) and size wise small (<25cm³) solution that would give me a somewhat stable 230VDC? (I can't find any ICs that can deal with that kind of voltage.)

---

**Addendum 1:**

- all LEDs are on when behind the rectifier, so I guess the lamps already contain a rectifier inside, just nothing to smooth the waveform

**Addendum 2:**

I went with the answer by hacktastical

So full bridge rectifier + capacitor + NTC.

The lights are stable. They do not get any hotter than before (measured with contactless thermometer) and have been running for hours at a time without a problem. Those may not be photo lights and therefore their color representation is not perfect but they do not distort the colors too much and that is good enough for a base lighting. (We do not need 100% accurate colors.) The rest is done with additional DC powered photo lights and colored reflectors. The wohle thing cost us something between 5 and 10 € if I remember correctly.

Comment: You could use a choke input filter, but I'm pretty sure a suitable choke would be bigger than what you want.

Comment: I'd just put a UPS with line regulation in.

Comment: There shouldn't be a stroboscopic effect from an LED light with a decent power supply. The LEDs need constant DC current at 350mA and a decent power supply will deliver that. If those don't, return to seller and get decent ones.

Comment: Why not just buy [battery powered LED work lights](https://www.milwaukeetool.com/Products/Lighting/Task-Lighting)?

Comment: @VoltageSpike, that's still AC from the UPS.

Comment: I make my own LED lights that work off of mains voltage converted to DC, however I use constant-current sinks to keep LED brightness fixed. I use a MJE340 NPN to fix the current and remove all ripple. Not sure if you are ready to work with transistors. The LED current must be known first.

Comment: @drmioshie regulated AC, the comment assumed that people would then know how to convert it to DC

Comment: Holly  These Floodlights are only <$25 each plus frame.  So unfortunately they are never suitable for photography unless your shutter is sync to the line peak voltage. Power supplies can cost more as much as the LEDs . But you paid too much for those.    Consider DC powered Flood or spot lights with a diffuser panel https://www.amazon.com/OFFROADTOWN-Driving-Lights-Waterproof-Warranty/dp/B076F4HJQ6

Comment: A POSSIBLE solution that is "easy & cheap enough" to try is to use a light dimmer unit followed by your full bridge plus rectifier. Cheap dimmers usually use "phase angle control" so the waveform is truncated to a variable extent at the start of the cycle. This means that the peak voltage is usually about the same and if lightly loaded the DC will be at about the same level as before :-(. However, as you reduce the dimmer output level you may achieve a result that is satisfactory.  ...

Comment: ... There re enough variables there to make it not certain, but it's probably worth trying. A more certain but more costly method is to use a 'variac' variable output voltage transformer. These do not distort the waveform.

Comment: Are you sure the LED's are flickering at 50Hz or is it just that your camera shutter is running at some multiple or beat frequency of 50Hz? I'd be checking your assumptions there.
Also, most LED bulbs, even cheap ones, rectify mains and then use a driver chip which means your suggestion of adding things external to the unit may do absolutely nothing to the power supply the LED's see inside the unit. BigClive on youtube has many excellent LED bulb/light teardowns and explanations, I'd start there if you're not sure how all this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how your LED lights work. There's a number of different types of off-the-line LED driving systems - simple diode bridge with filter, DC-DC, capacitor-dropped, etc.

Based on your experiment your lights may be a simple bridge kind (can you take one apart?) Normally, the internal bridge will be rectifying the 230VAC to 325VDC, same as what you are doing externally. So your external bridge+cap should not cause any harm: all the lamp internal components are up to the voltage task.

The one issue I would be concerned with is heating one half of the bridge more than the other since when you apply DC, only 2 out of the 4 diodes are conducting 100% of the time, vs. 50/50 with AC connected.

Aside from that you have basic safety to contend with. My suggestions would be to add the following to your recifier: fuse, NTC inrush protector, transient suppressor. These are the same elements you would find on a AC-to-DC power supply.

Comment: I was already looking into using an NTC so thats easy to add, stressing half the LEDs could be a problem, however all LEDs are on so I guess there already is a rectifier inside the lamp which would mean they already run on 325V, the lights are sealed so they are waterproof, therefore I would rather not open them

Comment: Try using a regulated DC power supply, if that works it will eliminate the flicker. PS your link is broken. The proper solution is to get photo quality lights.

Comment: If OP's lights are doing any of these things internally (and high chance they are), doing anything else externally will have no effect - if they are purely rectifying AC to DC and smoothing (which would be an _uncommon_ LED driving method), adding extra smoothing internally (just soldering more/larger capacitors in) is about all you can do.

Answer (score 0):

A POSSIBLE solution that is "easy & cheap enough" to try is to use a light dimmer unit followed by your full bridge rectifier plus filter capacitor.

Cheap dimmers usually use "phase angle control", so the waveform is truncated to a variable extent at the start of the cycle. This means that the peak voltage is usually about the same and if lightly loaded the DC will be at about the same level as before :-(.
However, as you reduce the dimmer output level you may achieve a result that is satisfactory. There re enough variables there to make it not certain, but it's probably worth trying.

Some dimmers provide high frequency PWM switching of the input AC waveform and so give a far less distorted output waveform.
They are less common and probably substantially more expensive.

A fairly [**'Heath Robinson'**](https://www.google.com/search?q=heath+robinson&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1ga27kO3jAhWo73MBHZaEBrIQ_AUIESgB&biw=1105&bih=685&dpr=2.5)*  solution is to place a load of about half the LED light effective resistance in series with the rectifier plus LEDs - either in the AC or DC sides. This could be eg several 100 Watt incandescent light bulbs in parallel or perhaps a domestic toaster element (in or out of toaster :-) ). [Stove element, electric kettle element, ... ].
Some experiment would probably be required but the result could be effective and lowish cost if not very pretty.

A more certain but more costly method is to use a 'variac' variable output voltage transformer.
These do not distort the waveform.

It may be (or may not) that use of a 220:110V step down transformer plus bridge rectifier will be adequate. Peak voltage is then Vin x 1/2 x 1.414 ~~~= 160 VDC if well filtered. Whether your LEDs handle that well is tbd. 230:110 or similar transformers are often available at relatively low cost for their power ratings.

Unlikely but possible: A transfomer with tappings or secondary windings that give you about 230V:160VAC  will give you about 230 VDC when peak rectified.

**_________________________________**

*If you don't know about Heath Robinson, it's worth making his acquaintance :-)

Comment: Across the pond we have "Rube Goldberg".

Comment: One more for you. If they can handle half the voltage, put two strings in series. Easy to find out what they think of that.